# JSON encode array parse correctly via Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, parsing

**EXPLANATION**

So from PHP to JavaScript encoded JSON array is sent in following:

```
$qa = array('question' => $question, 'a1' => $answer1, 'a2' => $answer2, 'a3' => $answer3);

echo json_encode($qa, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

In JavaScript when I'm using like this (take a look at `drawOutput`):

```
function getSuccessOutput() {
  getRequest(
      't.php', // demo-only URL
       drawOutput,
       drawError
  );
  return false;
}

function drawOutput(responseText) {   
    var container = document.getElementById('output');
    container.innerHTML = responseText;
}

function getRequest(url, success, error) {
    var req = false;
    try{
        // most browsers
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // IE
        try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            // try an older version
            try{
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!req) return false;
    if (typeof success != 'function') success = function () {};
    if (typeof error!= 'function') error = function () {};
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req .readyState == 4){
            return req.status === 200 ? 
                success(req.responseText) : error(req.status)
            ;
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null);
    return req;
}
```

I got following output:

```
{"question":"This is my question?","a1":"answer1","a2":"answer2","a3":"answer3"}
```

---

**DESIRED RESULTS**

I need extract each value from this array and assign to variables, example:

```
var myQuestion = "This is my question?";
var answ1 = "answer1";
var answ2 = "answer2";
var answ3 = "answer3";
```

---

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

```
function drawOutput(responseText) {   
    var container = document.getElementById('output');

    container.innerHTML = responseText;
    // OUTPUT: {"question":"This is my question?","a1":"answer1","a2":"answer2","a3":"answer3"} 

    container.innerHTML = responseText[0];
    // OUTPUT: <

    container.innerHTML = responseText[a1];
    // OUTPUT: nothing (blank)    
}
```

Also I've tried:

```
function drawOutput(responseText) {
    $.getJSON("t.php", function(responseText){      
        var container = document.getElementById('output');
        var theObject = JSON.parse(responseText);
    container.innerHTML = theObject[a1];        
    });    
}
// OUTPUT: nothing (blank)
```

Also I've tried to use `var theObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseText));` instead of `var theObject = JSON.parse(responseText);` in this case output: `undefined`

If I'm using in following:

```
function drawOutput(responseText) {             
    var container = document.getElementById('output');
    var theObject = JSON.parse(responseText);
    container.innerHTML = theObject[a1];                
}
// Output: nothing (blank)
```

But I got an error in browser's console: `SCRIPT1014: Invalid character`

I've read many similar issues, but nothing helped in my case. Have you any ideas, how could I solve It?

**UPDATE**

That's what I'm trying now and have nothing as output (blank):

```
function drawOutput(responseText) {
    $.getJSON("t.php", function(responseText){     
        var question = theObject.question;        // Get the question
        var a1       = theObject.a1;              // Get the answers
        var a2       = theObject.a2;
        var a3       = theObject.a3;

        var container = document.getElementById('output');
        container.innerHTML = a1;
        alert(a1);
    });    
}
```

Comment: this is an object so try to use responseText.a1 or responseText['a1']

Comment: can you console.log the `var theObject` ?

Comment: if `responseText` is `{"question":...` how can `responseText[0]` be `<` ... it MUST be `{`

Comment: using `$.getJSON` you should never need to `JSON.parse` the response - it's alreday a plain ol' javascript object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing it is correct. If you get the text via `XMLHttpRequest`, you'll need to use `JSON.parse` on `responseText`. If you use jQuery's `$.getJSON`, it will do it for you and give you the *parsed* result.

The problem is how you're trying to access the values from the result. In `theObject[a1]`, you're trying to use a **variable** called `a1`, whose value will then be used as the name of the property to get. Instead, use `theObject.a1` or `theObject["a1"]`.

So here, where you're using `getJSON` and so it's *already* been parsed for you:

```js
function drawOutput() {
    $.getJSON("t.php", function(theObject){       // Note: Not `responseText`, a parsed object
        var question = theObject.question;        // Get the question
        var a1       = theObject.a1;              // Get the answers
        var a2       = theObject.a2;
        var a3       = theObject.a3;
        // ...use them...
    });    
}
```

---

Side note: Instead of separate `a1,`a2`, and`a3` properties on the object you're returning, you might consider using an array.

```php
$qa = array(
    'question' => $question,
    'answers' => array($answer1, $answer2, $answer3)
);
echo json_encode($qa);
```

then

```js
function drawOutput() {
    $.getJSON("t.php", function(theObject){      
        var question = theObject.question;        // Get the question
        var answers  = theObject.answers;         // Get the answers
        // ...use question, and `answers[0]` through `answers[2]`, where
        // you can get the number of answers from `answers.length`...
    });    
}
```

Comment: @JaromandaX: This seems to be a simple "send the data from here to there," there's nothing to suggest that the complicated version wouldn't have fixed names for the fields, either.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but nothing happens, when I'm trying to use `alert(a1);` or `var container = document.getElementById('output');
  container.innerHTML = a1;` in that place where you commented `// ...use them...`

Comment: Also I don't think so that I'm using `XMLHttpRequest`, that's almost all code what I'm using in PHP and JavaScript (p.s. javascript included in index.html, I don't know if It's matter).

Comment: @Infinity: Apologies, I'd grabbed one of your code snippets that was using `getJSON`, but didn't notice (because it had the `responseText` argument on `drawOutput`). I've just fixed that above. I said it in the answer but for emphasis: If you use `XMLHttpRequest` directly, you'll need `JSON.parse`. If you use jQuery's `$.getJSON`, jQuery will do the parsing for you.

Comment: @Infinity: That should be just fine if you're returning the resource with the correct `Content-Type` header indicating the charset being used.

Comment: In top of my PHP file I'm using: `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');`

Comment: And after connecting to database in PHP file I'm using `if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {.....`

Comment: I've removed parse from It (using your updated answer), but now I got nothing (blank as before). Looks like `$.getJSON()` is not called.

Comment: @Infinity: That's not the way SO works. You don't fold answers into the question. I'm sorry, but I don't think we can really help you any further. Based on the information you've supplied in the question, the above will work. I suggest thorough debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can access object values with one of these method:

```js
var responseText = '{"question":"This is my question?","a1":"answer1","a2":"answer2","a3":"answer3"} ';
var theObject = JSON.parse(responseText);
console.log(theObject['a1']); // a1 in string
console.log(theObject.a1); // Gives the same result
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but It returns me nothing (blank) as in last sample in my question. In browsers console I see an error `SCRIPT1014: Invalid character`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you need to **json_encode** your response :

```
$ServerResponse= json_encode($MyJSON);
```

In Javascript you need to **JSON.parse** the response you got from PHP :

```
var myJSONObject = JSON.parse(ServerResponse);
```

After that , you have a normal Object in your hands , and that is **myJsonObject**. You can access its properties either with the use of "dot" (Eg. myJsonObject.PROPERTY_NAME) or with brackets (Eg myJsonObject["PROPERTY_NAME"]).